# Issue with training a face recognition model using Tkinter and OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, tkinter, training-data

**Description:**
I'm currently working on a face recognition project using Tkinter for the GUI and OpenCV for image processing on visual studio. My goal is to train the model with a dataset of images and display a popup message indicating the completion of training. However, I'm encountering an issue where nothing happens when I click the "TRAIN DATA" button. The window doesn't open and there are no error messages displayed.

**Code**:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from tkinter import messagebox
import mysql.connector
import cv2
import os
import numpy as np

class Train:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.geometry("1530x790+0+0")
        self.root.title("Face Recognition System")  
        
        title_lbl= Label(self.root, text= "TRAIN DATA SET",font=("times new roman",35,"bold"), bg="white",fg="darkgreen")
        title_lbl.place(x=0,y=0,width=1530, height=45)
        
        img_top= Image.open(r"C:\Users\The-Javeira\Desktop\test\images\b.jpg")
        img_top= img_top.resize((1530,325), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        self.photoimg_top= ImageTk.PhotoImage(img_top)
        
        f_lbl2= Label(self.root,image=self.photoimg_top)
        f_lbl2.place(x=0,y=55,width=1530,height=325)  
        
         #button
        b1_1=Button(self.root ,text="TRAIN DATA", command=self.train_classifier, cursor="hand2",font=("times new roman",30,"bold"), bg="red",fg="white")
        b1_1.place(x=0,y=380,width=1530,height=60)
        
        img_bottom= Image.open(r"C:\Users\The-Javeira\Desktop\test\images\train2.JPEG")
        img_bottom= img_bottom.resize((1530,325), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        self.photoimg_bottom= ImageTk.PhotoImage(img_bottom)
        
        f_lbl2= Label(self.root,image=self.photoimg_bottom)
        f_lbl2.place(x=0,y=440 ,width=1530,height=325)  
        
    def train_classifier(self):
        data_dir=("images data")
        path=[os.path.join(data_dir,file) for  file in os.listdir(data_dir)]
        
        faces=[]
        ids=[]
        
        for image in  path:
            img=Image.open(image).convert('L')    #Gray Scale Image
            imageNp=np.array(img,'uint8')
            id=int(os.path.split(image)[1].split('.')[1])
            
            faces.append(imageNp)
            ids.append(id)  
            cv2.imshow("Training Data",imageNp)
            cv2.waitKey(1)==13
        
        ids=np.array(ids)
        
        #============Train the classifier and Save ===========
      
        clf=cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
        clf.train(faces,ids)
        clf.write("Classifier.xml")
        messagebox.showinfo("Result","Training Datasets Completed!!")
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    obj = Train(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

**Expected Behavior:**
When I click the "TRAIN DATA" button, I expect a window to open showing the training progress with images being displayed.
Once the training is complete, I expect a popup message saying "Training Datasets Completed!!" to appear.
The classifier should be saved as "Classifier.xml" in the specified directory.

**Actual Behavior:**
When I click the "TRAIN DATA" button, nothing happens. The window doesn't open, and there are no error messages displayed.
The expected popup message indicating the completion of training doesn't appear.
No "Classifier.xml" file is created in the specified directory

**additional Information**
All the required dependencies are installed.

Comment: never mix different GUIs. you did by combining tkinter and OpenCV's `imshow`. -- never run a lot of computation in an event handler. use threads.

Comment: Not working i am confused whats the problem. code should store the train data in haarcascade_frontaldace_default.xml and classifier.xml folder bur i tried everything in my knowledge but nothing changed. its my fyp and i have to submit as soon as possible. so kindly help me it  would be so appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try executing your training method in a different process or thread and displaying your message when the thread is finished. I believe your issue is that you are using a **for loop** in a gui.

Comment: Not working i am confused whats the problem. code should store the train data in haarcascade_frontaldace_default.xml and classifier.xml folder bur i tried everything in my knowledge but nothing changed. its my fyp and i have to submit as soon as possible. so kindly help me it  would be so appreciated

Answer (score 0):

first uninstall pip uninstall opencv-contrib-python
then reinstall pip install opencv-contrib python
and regarding this "clf=cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()"
write,
"clf=cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer.create()"
and see if it works

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).